# calling multiple functions in javascript without overwriting the original - polymorphism problem?

Tags: javascript, scope, youtube-api, redefinition

I am using two different plugins requiring the onyoutubeplayerready function:

```
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tubular/
http://badsyntax.github.com/jquery-youtube-player/examples/player.html
```

Both of them declare and initialize the onyoutubeplayerready function. Hence, one of the plugins ends up not working.

I have these three in head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.youtube.player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.tubular.js"></script>
```

Both of the scripts are defined right before the ending body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

(function($){
    var config =  {

        repeatPlaylist: 1,

        // Custom playlist
        playlist: {
            title: 'Random videos',
            videos: [
                { id: 'CJCTiC1po8E', title: 'VCore Intro'},
                { id: 'ydCF922o944', title: 'VCore Admin' }, 
                { id: 'yC-_eqPqaoY', title: 'VCore Admin System' },
                { id: '7qkE30S2Btk', title: 'VCore Site' }
            ]
        }

        /*
        // Youtube playlist
        playlist: {
            playlist: '71B8152559FA2805'
        }

        // Latest user videos
        playlist: {
            user: 'TheSensless'
        }
        */
    };

    $('.youtube-player').player(config)

})(this.jQuery);
//]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
function initializeTub(){
    $('body').tubular('_VKW_M_uVjw','wrapper');

}
$('a').click(function(){initializeTub()}); //clicking a random link just to test it
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

@epascarello

I tried your solution. The one that comes first has this:

```
            window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(id){ 
                console.log('2');


                var player = document.getElementById(id);

                player.addEventListener("onStateChange", 'onytplayerStateChange' + id);

                player.addEventListener('onError', 'onytplayerStateChange' + id);

                window['onytplayerStateChange' + id](9);
            };
```

The one that comes second has this:

```
var _onYouTubePlayerReady = onYouTubePlayerReady;
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
console.log('1');
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
 ytplayer.setPlaybackQuality('medium');
 ytplayer.mute();

_onYouTubePlayerReady( playerId );
```

}

The console outputs this:

```
2
2
```

Hence, the one that is declared first is called both times. And the second one never is called because console never outputs 1.

But according to the book JavaScript Programmer's Reference:

```
In fact, if you attempt to overload a function, the most recent definition will be used. This is because of the mutable nature of objects such as functions.
```

So if that's the case:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.youtube.player.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.tubular.js"></script>
```

Since the one function defined in tubular comes second, why isn't that the one that is pointed to when the function is eventually called? Notice the tubular script comes second.

Also, Fred's solution didn't work either.

I tried this and it didn't work either:

```
var _onYouTubePlayerReady = onYouTubePlayerReady;
function _onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
console.log('1');
ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
   ytplayer.setPlaybackQuality('medium');
   ytplayer.mute();

}
_onYouTubePlayerReady( playerId );
```

By the way, I have no clue when this is called, apparently magically a call to google at some point, but definitely not in any of scripts that came with plugin.

Thanks for response.

Comment: yeah, I don't see where the function is being called though.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to fire a custom event with jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function (I don't know the pure JS way to do this). Then you can change your code to the following:
`Youtube.player.js`:

```
window.onMyCustomEventOne = function(id){ 
  var player = document.getElementById(id);
  player.addEventListener("onStateChange", 'onytplayerStateChange' + id);
  player.addEventListener('onError', 'onytplayerStateChange' + id);

            window['onytplayerStateChange' + id](9);
        };
    }
```

`Tubular`:

```
function onMyCustomEventTwo(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.setPlaybackQuality('medium');
  ytplayer.mute();
}
```

and in jQuery:

```
window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(vars){
  $('window').trigger('myCustomEventOne',vars).trigger('myCustomEventTwo',vars);
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You need to change the code which calls `onMyCustomEventTwo` in Tubular as well, but since you didn't post that code, I couldn't change it.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the one that comes second to something like this

```
var _onYouTubePlayerReady = onYouTubePlayerReady;
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    //whatever code needs to be here
    _onYouTubePlayerReady( playerId );
}
```

Comment: didn't work. I updated my question to show the results of the console on why it didn't work.